# I would like to know the origin of the following formula

Tags: circuit-analysis, transformer, impedance, autotransformer, secondary-winding

I don't understand what's in the red circle.

Why is the unit 's' and what does 's' stand for?

Why must we divide the current at Open-circuit test by the voltage at Open-circuit test?

I don't understand the origin of the formula in the red circle.
[image]

Comment: `Why is the unit 's'`  ... it's not `s`, it is `S`

Comment: Capital `S` is the unit for `siemens` (used to be called mhos).

Comment: how does the formula compare to the Ohm's law formulas?

Answer (score 5):

S stands for [siemens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siemens_(unit)), it's the unit of conductance. It's the inverse of ohms, so instead of V/A = \$\Omega\$ you get A/V = S.

They could just have well done the calculation the other way around to get ohms, but they wanted to use siemens in the next calculations, maybe to make the math easier.

Comment: Tip: 'S' or 'siemens'. SI units named after a person are lowercase when spelt out.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid it's an error. Making the equivalent of a transformer by presenting all as they were in the secondary side should affect to primary side impedances or as well their inverses i.e. admittances by the winding ratio squared. The formula for the magnetization admittance leaves the primary idle current as is. It also should be converted to the secondary side.

It's not at all uncommon to use admittance 1/Z instead of impedance Z for a little shorter formulas. S (=siemens) is 1/ohm as already said by others.